# Ordination plot - colouring points with a different colour

Tags: r, plot

I have a database of 9 sites and thousands of species.

I created a ordination and a plot using

```
ord = metaMDS (vegan)
plot(ord, type ="n")
points(ord, display="species", col="grey")
text (ord, display="sites")
```

I got the following plot
[image]

I need to get some of the species points in red, like in the following plot (ignore the numbers next to the red points)

[image]

I have done it before just using the plot function but not sure now how to get it.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that shows how to assign red color to some selected points.

```
library(vegan)

data(dune)
ord <- metaMDS(dune)
plot(ord, type ="n")

# Positions of red-colored points
red.pts <- c(2,3,4,5,10,15,20)
cols = rep("black",30)
cols[red.pts] <- "red"

points(ord, display="species", pch=20, cex=2, col=cols)
text(ord, display="sites")
```

[image]